# PostgreSQL, AirFlow: небольшая проблема f-string: single '}' is not allowed

Tags: postgresql, psycopg2, airflow

Всем привет.

Столкнулся с проблемой. Есть у меня такой SQL-запрос в AirFlow:

SQL_QUERY = (f"""

...

```
WITH all_unputs AS (
        SELECT fct_dc.collect_project_id AS fct_dc_collect_project_id, replace(inp.text, '},{', '},-{') AS text,
```

...

""")

Где-то в месте '},{', '},-{' он начинает ругаться, что не корректный синтаксис и на закрыты скобки

```
f-string: single '}' is not allowed
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Что-то могу понять как это обойти?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема то ни в БД ни в airflow. Вы создаете строку запроса с помощью `f-string` (форматированные строковые литералы), при этом все открывающие фигурные ковычки в тексте будут интерпретироваться как ожидание передачи параметров, аналог `.format`.

Если Вы не передаете никаких параметров, то достаточно убрать `f` перед строкой запроса.